# using __attribute__ ((weak)) leads to warning "redundant redeclaration of xxx", any way to avoid?

Tags: c, gcc

When I use `__attribute__ ((weak))` like in [this post](http://www.kolpackov.net/pipermail/notes/2004-March/000006.html) I get warnings from gcc about redeclaring the symbol, while all I do is adding an attribute. Can the attribute be attached differently? The warnings I get look like this:

```
threads.c:53: warning: redundant redeclaration of ‘pthread_once’
/usr/include/pthread.h:478: note: previous declaration of ‘pthread_once’ was here
```

Comment: Do you declare your own verion of pthread_once in threads.c?

Comment: yes I do (in order to add the attribute)
  #ifdef __GNUC__
  #ifdef linux
  #if (__GNUC__ == 3 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 3) || (__GNUC__ > 3)
  extern int pthread_once (pthread_once_t *__once_control,
                         void (*__init_routine) (void))
      __attribute((weak));
  ...

Comment: You can't #include <pthread.h>, then, because you declare the function twice. You can make a copy of pthread.h, change the declaration of pthread_once there and include that instead.

Comment: That's unfortunately not very practical. I think there must be another way to add the __attribute((weak)) to a symbol then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - GCC allows you to use `#pragma weak` to declare symbols as weak, so you can do this instead:

```
#include <pthread.h>

#pragma weak pthread_create
#pragma weak pthread_mutex_init
#pragma weak pthread_mutex_lock
#pragma weak pthread_mutex_unlock 
#pragma weak pthread_mutex_destroy

/* ... code ... */
```

(Documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Weak-Pragmas.html).)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pthread stub library like the one from http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/pthread-stubs/ which avoids the need to create your own stubs.

If you only need to run on fairly modern systems, either libc will provide a set of stubs for most commonly used functions for making things thread-safe or libpthread is integrated into libc. Note that stubs for `pthread_once` may not call the passed function ever. (Some libraries use this to detect if they are in the threaded or unthreaded programming environment.)